# jQuery on dropdown event, dropdown visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, show, dropdown

Is there any jQuery event that catches when a selectbox dropdown is shown/visible?  I am trying to populate the selectbox with values once the dropdown is shown.

```
<select id="foo">
   <option value="">----</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="1"> Option1 </option>                           
   <option value="2"> Option 2 </option>
</select>

//I need something like this
jQuery('#foo:dropdown').on('visible', function(){
  //Do what you need to do
});
```

I tried using on change, but that is not the exact event I am looking for, because I am trying to populate the box with values before any selection is actually made.  Furthermore I cant use on click, because although it works by populating the selectbox with values, once I make a selection, the script is called again and the box is reset in a never ending circle.

Comment: There is no such event for `<select>` beyond using `focus`. Why would it not be previously populated? Seems like an unusual requirement. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I have a country-state-city api that is auto-populated depending on certain selections.  I can easily have it populate on page load, but that is not the solution I am looking for

Comment: Normally change of the dependent `<select>` would be used to populate the next in chain and if needed can trigger change on page load also

Comment: Yes, that is the way it's set up.  The problem comes in that these values are saved for the user and I don't the function that does this to fire every time the pageboy is loaded, because then the values the user has will be deleted just by loading the page.

Comment: That is easily solved in more conventional ways such as store value before loading options. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So kind of building off Barry's answer, this is the solution I have come up with.

When the page is first loaded, a var is assigned with a value of 0.  When the selectbox is clicked, the value is immediately increased by 1.  The function then checks whether the var is now equal to 1, and if it is, this represents that the dropdown is open, and the function fires.  After you do what needed to be done, the value is decreased by 2 (new value of -1). This is so that when you make a choice in the selectbox (make another click), whatever you only wanted to do when the selectbox is shown does not fire again.  However, it will fire the next time you click it because the value will equal 1 again. Rise and repeat.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aa = 0;
    $('#foo').on('click', function () {  
      aa++;      
      if (aa == 1) { //Basically, is dropdown open?
        //Do what you need to do when dropdown is open
        aa = -1; //Now assign new value to aa
      }         
    });  
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question and a fun to answer one. This can be done by using 'click' and yes I know it will keep firing everytime you click the select box. But wait, there is a trick to fix this, we can set a flag for this. So, the flag (variable) is false when loading the script and the first time you click the select it gets set to true and the script will only execute once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var first_time = false;
  $('select').on('click', function() {
    if (!first_time) {
      console.log('Yes, here I am!');
      first_time = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So what if user needs to use it again? `click` and `<select>` don't work well together. Note that `focus` would probably be better than using click

Comment: The problem was that it got called over and over again, so this is the solution. Of course it is possible to set the flag to false again, when needed. To be honest, I can't think of a scenario where you would populate the checkboxes when clicking select.

Comment: Hi, Barry.  Thank you for the suggestion but the charlietfl is in fact right and I need to be able to click it over and over

Comment: "Note that focus would probably be better than using click" I don't agree with that. Focus will also fire when the user uses tab and selects the select element, but it will not open the selectbox.

Comment: is not intended to open it...just do what op needs. To be honest i don't think either is a good approach

Comment: @charlietfl This is starting to get pretty weird. It has to do stuff on click, over and over again, but it can't run over and over again...

Comment: @LearntoExcel Just use click and do the stuff you need. But before doing that, check if the checkboxes are already populated. That way, it will execute everytime you click, but it won't do anything if the data you placed is already there.

Comment: There is most likely a simpler solution all the way around based on events on other controls. This whole thing seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If I'm forced to do what I need another way, I will.  I was just trying to see if I can accomplish it this way to make it easier.

Comment: @BarryMeijer if you are happy its a good question, you should give learntoexcel an upvote

Comment: @TobyAllen Done! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @charlietfl came up with a solution if you guys are interested.